# How to get only textbox controls using windows API's?

Tags: c#, winapi, spy++

I need to get controls from other application but only textbox controls.

How can I do it?

I have this code at the moment:

```
public static List<IntPtr> FindWindowControl(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);

    try
    {
        Helpers.WinApi.EnumWindowProc childProc = new Helpers.WinApi.EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
        Helpers.WinApi.EnumChildWindows(hWnd, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
            listHandle.Free();
    }
    return result;
}

private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
{
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
    List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
    if (list == null)
        throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");

    string className = Helpers.WinApi.GetWinClass(handle);
    if (className.Equals("Edit") || className.Equals("RICHEDIT60W"))
    {
        list.Add(handle);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that for applications created in .NET, TextBoxes are created using other class, so they are not found.

When using Spy++, I saw that the textbox control has the class called:
WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r14_ad1.

That suggested me that I cannot use class name, or, can I safely look for the word EDIT inside the class name?

Comment: Use UI Automation, which has several C# APIs available for it.

Comment: Can you ellaborate a little more? I have Google'd for UI Automation and I have found it has a lot of classes available. Furthermore, it is only for WPF, isn't it? I am no using WPF.

Comment: It is not only for WPF. It is an automation API, designed to painlessly allow you to navigate and manipulate the window hierarchy. To use it, ask for the provider for the toplevel, and traverse its children, looking for the edit fields you want by name and/or type.